# Is there is any better way to create a class that generates a random gender of population and assign to the community based on the n?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

Python class that generates random gender of the population (M/F) and assign it to the community based on n?

1. Popultion count = 30
2. example population count is 30 (Adult,old,kid)
3. Age Distibution Adult 50% , Kids 30% old 20%
4. Community data

   ```
      Community_num    Community_name  Community_polygon   Community_population
      301              new york        Mutipolgon([])      10
      303              JFK             Mutipolgon([])      10
      304              River side      Mutipolgon([])      10
   ```

Expected out

```
 Community_num  Community_name  Community_polygon   Community_population Gender Age  Age_Group 

  301               new york        Mutipolgon([])      10                F      27 Adult
  301               new york        Mutipolgon([])      10                M      27 Adult
  301               new york        Mutipolgon([])      10                M      10 Kids
  301               new york        Mutipolgon([])      10                M      50 Old
```

Code try

```
def GeneratePeople(time, n):
   
    people = [None] * n
   
    for i in range(0,n):
       
        people[i] = Person(Gender.Male, 30, time)
       
       
    return people
```

I get the basic but I need help on this.

Age

```
kids - below 15
adult - above 15 to 45
old  - 45 above
```

Comment: Do you want 30 people overall or 30 people from each community? also, what's the age distribution within child, adult, and old?

Comment: @Roy2012 Sorry I will update age distribution, i.e count 100, 50% adult, 30% kids, 20% old.

Comment: each community needs to assign the population based on the community population count.

Comment: So 30 people overall?

Comment: yes initial people count 30

Comment: Did you write any code to try implement this - edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do that:

```
df["dummy"] = df.Community_population.map(lambda x: list(range(x)))
df = df.explode("dummy")
df["Gender"] = np.random.choice(["M", "F"], len(df))

df["Age_Group"] = np.random.choice(["child", "adult", "old"], len(df), p=[.3, .5, .2])
df.loc[df.Age_Group == "old", "age"] = np.random.randint(50, 90, len(df[df.Age_Group == "old"] ))

df.loc[df.Age_Group == "child", "age"] = np.random.randint(0, 18, len(df[df.Age_Group == "child"] ))
df.loc[df.Age_Group == "adult", "age"] = np.random.randint(18, 50, len(df[df.Age_Group == "adult"] ))
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Let me check and update you